# (Error: 11200) HTTP retrieval failure Twilio's servers were unable to fetch a non-error response from the designated URL

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-php

I have a function that allows me to send a photo and text to a number using Twilio, but when I change the route it gives me the previous error:

```
$messageService->sendMessage(
    config('twilio.whatsapp'),
    "whatsapp:{$number}",
    $text,
    route('send-img-whatsapp.jpeg', $param)
);
```

I already verified the route with its respective parameter and it gives me 200
I don't know if it's a twilio error or my server

Comment: _"I already verified the route with its respective parameter and it gives me 200"_ - operative word in there being "me." Just because you get a positive response when making the request from your end, doesn't necessarily mean, it will be the same, when Twilio's system makes the request. Maybe you have some "image hotlinking" protection in place, or the whole thing is protected by something like CloudFlare, or similar? What do your server's log files have to say about the request in question?